# How to update swing GUI from inside a long method(I want the TextArea to be immediately updated)?

Tags: java, swing

trying to develop a simple GUI application in NetBeans.

I want to create some kind of a GUI logging system, to write the current action that's being performed by the application, into a TextArea.

As a simple example, I created a JFrame form which contains only 2 objects: a "Start" button and a TextArea.

When the "Start" button is pressed, it invokes some kind of a lengthy method that should take some time (say, 10 seconds) to complete running, and while this method is running, I want to append text to the TextArea from withing this lengthy method (and of course I want the TextArea to be immediately updated).

My problem is that I cannot find the proper way of doing that. Anyway I tried doing this, when I press on the "Start" button, the application freezes for 10 seconds, without updating the TextArea like I wanted. Only when the method finishes, I see the update to the TextArea.

Here's a sample code:

```
private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       textArea.setText(i + "\n");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

}

Comment: i just have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Thread.sleep(...) in a listener. All listener code is executed on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. The GUI won't be able repaint itself until the loop is finished executing.

The solution is to use a separate `Thread` for the long running task. One way to do this is to use a `SwingWorkder`. Once the code is executing on a separate Thread you can use Thread.sleep(...) (if necessary).

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on the `EDT` and on using a `SwingWorker`. The tutorial contains a working example to get you started.

Comment: can you please help me just in that litle example ... cuz i tried to understand how does swingworker work

Comment: @Yassine, read the tutorial. The section on `Tasks That Have Interim Results` might be the place to start for a working example. download the working example and then modify the working example for your requirement. Or you can search the forum for other examples that use SwingWorker. I don't know what you find confusing. If you need more help then post a proper [mcve] that shows what you have tried.

Comment: thank you dude ^-^

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to create a new Thread and execute the 10 second code right there. Otherwise, the GUI will freeze instead

Comment: (1-) answer has already been given. There is no need to repeat the same suggestion.

Comment: Oops, i didn't see it sorry! @camickr